# Does passing a whole dataframe to a function or just few columns make a difference in terms of computational speed?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Suppose I have a data frame with a large number of columns

```
ncol = 40
sample_size = 300

my_matrix <- replicate(ncol, runif(sample_size, 0, 3))
my_df <- data.frame(my_matrix)
names(my_df) <- paste0("x", 1:ncol)
epsilon <- rnorm(sample_size, 0, 0.2) 
my_df$y <- 1+3*my_df$x1 + epsilon
```

I pass the data frame to a function which needs only three of its columns to do the job (in my real codes, the function may use more than 3 columns, but I'm trying to keep things simple here):

```
library(ggplot2)

idle_plotter <- function(dataframe, x_string, y_string, color_string){
    p <- ggplot(dataframe, aes_string(x = x_string, y = y_string, color = color_string)) +
        geom_point()
    print(p)
}
```

Does it make a difference, in terms of speed, if I pass the whole `my_df` to  `idle_plotter`, or just the three columns `idle_plotter` needs? If the whole data frame is copied on call, I guess it does, but if R is pass-by-reference, it shouldn't. In my tests it doesn't seem to make a difference, but I need to know if:

- this is a rule, in which case I can continue to pass data frames to functions
- or just dumb luck, because the function is simple and/or the data frame is not huge. In this case I **must** abandon the habit of passing full data frames, or I risk making my code slower than it already is.

Comment: I don't know about speed, but passing all your data to `ggplot` will take up more space. `Ggplot` stores a copy of the data you pass it. Try this `plot <- idle_plotter(my_df, "x1", "y", color = "x2"); plot$data[[1]]`. Also to show that its a copy you can use `data.table::address(plot$data[[1]]);
data.table::address(my_df)`. The addresses returned should be different.

Comment: Apart from cases where the function deliberately makes a copy (as Mike pointed out applies here) or modifies parts of the input it doesn't need (triggering copy-on-modify), I guess there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not seem to make a big difference: run with your data

```
idle_plotter_df <- function(dataframe, x_string, y_string, color_string){
    p <- ggplot(dataframe, aes_string(x = x_string, y = y_string, color = color_string)) +
        geom_point()
    print(p)
}

idle_plotter_col <- function(x_string, y_string, color_string){
  p <- ggplot(NULL) + aes_string(x = x_string, y = y_string, color = color_string) +
    geom_point()
  print(p)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  idle_plotter_df(my_df, "x1", "x2", "x3"),
  idle_plotter_col("my_df$x1", "my_df$x2", "my_df$x3"), times = 10L)
```

Result

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
             idle_plotter_df(my_df, "x1", "x2", "x3") 168.8718 260.0504 265.3658 270.8738 272.5409 323.3371    10
 idle_plotter_col("my_df$x1", "my_df$x2", "my_df$x3") 264.6850 276.4981 293.8205 284.9820 300.3936 356.9910    10
```